# Execution failed for task ':app:runCheckstyle'

Tags: android, performance, checkstyle

After Implementing Huawei Ads Into My App I Am Facing The Following Error
Execution failed for task ':app:runCheckstyle'.

> Checkstyle rule violations were found. See the report at: file:///Users/mac/Downloads/youtube%20video%20downloader/app/build/reports/checkstyle/runCheckstyle.html
> Checkstyle files with violations: 6
> Checkstyle violations by severity: [error:14, warning:8]

Here is complete Error List :

Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug] in project /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader

> Configure project :app
> Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

> Task :app:clean
> Task :app:formatKtlint
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:runCheckstyle
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:1: File does not end with a newline. [NewlineAtEndOfFile]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:126:15: '=' is not followed by whitespace. [WhitespaceAround]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:128:30: '=' is not followed by whitespace. [WhitespaceAround]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:128:30: '=' is not preceded with whitespace. [WhitespaceAround]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:129:36: '=' is not followed by whitespace. [WhitespaceAround]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:129:36: '=' is not preceded with whitespace. [WhitespaceAround]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:182:20: Variable 'bannerView' should be declared final. [FinalLocalVariable]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:185:17: Variable 'adParam' should be declared final. [FinalLocalVariable]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:198:17: Variable 'adParam' should be declared final. [FinalLocalVariable]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:205:9: 'if' is not followed by whitespace. [WhitespaceAfter]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:205:17: '%' is not followed by whitespace. [WhitespaceAround]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:205:17: '%' is not preceded with whitespace. [WhitespaceAround]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:205:19: '==' is not followed by whitespace. [WhitespaceAround]
> [ant:checkstyle] [ERROR] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/MainActivity.java:205:19: '==' is not preceded with whitespace. [WhitespaceAround]
> [ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/database/stream/model/StreamStateEntity.java:72:5: Definition of 'equals()' without corresponding definition of 'hashCode()'. [EqualsHashCode]
> [ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/player/playqueue/PlayQueue.java:504:5: Definition of 'equals()' without corresponding definition of 'hashCode()'. [EqualsHashCode]
> [ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/settings/tabs/Tab.java:114:5: Definition of 'equals()' without corresponding definition of 'hashCode()'. [EqualsHashCode]
> [ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/settings/tabs/Tab.java:360:9: Definition of 'equals()' without corresponding definition of 'hashCode()'. [EqualsHashCode]
> [ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/settings/tabs/Tab.java:434:9: Definition of 'equals()' without corresponding definition of 'hashCode()'. [EqualsHashCode]
> [ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/settings/tabs/Tab.java:579:9: Definition of 'equals()' without corresponding definition of 'hashCode()'. [EqualsHashCode]
> [ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/streams/Mp4FromDashWriter.java:145:5: Method length is 259 lines (max allowed is 150). [MethodLength]
> [ant:checkstyle] [WARN] /Users/mac/Downloads/youtube video downloader/app/src/main/java/org/schabi/newpipe/streams/WebMWriter.java:124:5: Method length is 206 lines (max allowed is 150). [MethodLength]

> Task :app:runCheckstyle FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:runCheckstyle'.

> Checkstyle rule violations were found. See the report at: file:///Users/mac/Downloads/youtube%20video%20downloader/app/build/reports/checkstyle/runCheckstyle.html
> Checkstyle files with violations: 6
> Checkstyle violations by severity: [error:14, warning:8]

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 24s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed

Comment: Could you provide some more information like the contents of the report?

Comment: Here is Complete Message

Answer (score 0):

Your "clue" (from above)

```
Checkstyle rule violations were found. See the report at: file:///Users/mac/Downloads/youtube%20video%20downloader/app/build/reports/checkstyle/runCheckstyle.html Checkstyle files with violations: 6 

Checkstyle violations by severity: [error:14, warning:8]
```

Note the "error:14".  That is the error total count.  (I wish they would have named it "errorTotalCount"...to make it more clear, but regardless....)

Perhaps you have set up a "maxErrors" setting.

See below.

If there are 50 or more checkstyle issues, your build will fail.

Sidenote :
Below shows a custom .xml file.  there is a "built in default" set of rules.

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

checkstyle {
    configFile = file('source/java/MyCustomCheckStyleRuleList.xml')
    toolVersion = '8.33'
    ignoreFailures = false
    showViolations = true
    maxErrors = 50
}
```